# Content types hierarchy inside my Apps

Tags: 2013, list, content-type

I have added a simple Issue tracking list inside my team site, and it will get "Issue" content type. but i have noted the following is that the new Issue tracking list's content type will be absed on "Issue" , but it will alos have a parent content type of type "Issue"? as follow:-

[image]

so is this because sharePoint automatically copy the content type insdie the list ?

Second question, and if i click on the parent Issue content type and i edit it , will i be editing the parent content type at the site level (same as going to Web Designer Galleries --> Site content types ), or SharePoint will also copy the parent ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a site content type to a list or library, it is called a list content type. The list content type is a child of the site content type from which it was created. It inherits all the attributes of its parent site content type, such as its document template, read-only setting, workflows, and columns. If the parent site content type for a list content type is updated, the child list content type can inherit these changes. A list content type can be customized for the specific list or library to which it is added. These customization's do not apply to the parent site content type.

If the child content type shares attributes with the parent site content type, those attributes might be overwritten when the list content type inherits changes from the parent. If the list content type has custom attributes that the parent content type does not have, these customization's are not overwritten.

Comment: so if i add a new site column to the list content type, then this new site column can not be overridden by the parent site content type, since the new site column does not exists in the parent site content type .. is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct